# Replace strings in one list with strings in another list

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists of city names that look like:

```
old_city = ['DORCHESTER', 'SOUTH EASTON', 'ASHLEY FALLS']
new_city = ['BOSTON', 'EASTON', 'SHEFFIELD']
```

In one column of my dataframe, I would like to replace every city that is in old_city with the corresponding city name in new_city. What I am doing is:

```
data['city'] = data['city'].replace('DORCHESTER','BOSTON')
data['city'] = data['city'].replace('SOUTH EASTON','EASTON')
data['city'] = data['city'].replace('ASHLEY FALLS','SHEFFIELD')
```

But this is very inefficient given that I have more than a hundred names to replace...

Are there any suggestions on better ways? I have read other similar questions, but none of them seem to have two lists like here...

Thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: Actually `data['city']` is not a list right? It's a pandas.Series

Comment: Yes `data['city']` is pandas.Series, a column in the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data.replace(old_city,new_city)`

Answer (score 1):

Do with

```
data['city'] = data['city'].replace(dict(zip(old_city,new_city)))
```

Comment: This is super helpful!! Thanks a lot for the advice!